# Rails 3: Sweeper not destroying fragments, thinks caching was disabled

Tags: caching, configuration, memcached, ruby-on-rails-3, fragment-caching

I want to expire fragments with a sweeper. The sweeper callbacks are executed, but the calls to expire_fragment do nothing, because (I assume) cache_configured? returns nil. Caching is configured and fragments are being created and used in my templates (verified it in the logs). What am I doing wrong?

application.rb

```
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", { # I use a real IP
    :compress => true,
    :namespace => "#{Rails.env}_r3"
  }
config.active_record.observers = [:auction_sweeper, :address_sweeper]
```

production.rb

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

auction_sweeper.rb

```
class AuctionSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper 
  observe Auction

  def after_create(auction)
    Rails.logger.info "AuctionSweeper.expire_details #{auction.id} #{cache_configured?.inspect}=#{perform_caching.inspect}&&#{cache_store.inspect}"
    expire_fragment("auction/#{auction.reference_sid}")
  end
end
```

In log files, cache_configured? is nil and so is perform_caching and cache_store.

```
AuctionSweeper.expire_details 12732 nil=nil&&nil
```

So I assume, that my fragments are not expired because the code of expire_fragment reads:

[File actionpack/lib/action_controller/caching/fragments.rb, line 87](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html#method-i-expire_fragment)

```
87:       def expire_fragment(key, options = nil)
88:         return unless cache_configured?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution (hack?) [here](http://stevencummings.name/2010/09/07/expire_fragment-with-rake-and-as-a-model-only-observer) that suggests to set @controller and it works for me.

```
class AuctionSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper 
  observe Auction

  def after_create(auction)
    @controller ||= ActionController::Base.new
    Rails.logger.info "AuctionSweeper.expire_details #{auction.id} #{cache_configured?.inspect}=#{perform_caching.inspect}&&#{cache_store.inspect}"
    expire_fragment("auction/#{auction.reference_sid}")
  end
end
```

Also a note to myself: remember to return true from before filters also in sweepers or you get ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved and wonder why.

Comment: Thank you! The hack with the @controller worked for me. It's strange that this is not mentioned in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share your `Rails.env` - caching is naturally disabled in `development` and `test` - maybe you missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the instance variable for the controller I use an initializer called cache_sweeping_observer.rb

```
class CacheSweepingObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  include ActiveSupport::Configurable
  include ActionController::Caching

  config_accessor :perform_caching

  class << self
    def config
      ActionController::Base.config
    end
  end
end
```

Then I inherit from it for any observer that is for sweeping caches.

```
class ModelSweeper < CacheSweepingObserver  
  observe Model

  def after_update(model)
    expire_fragment "#{model.id}"
    true
  end
end
```